# AWS-CLI. Синхронизация c S3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, синхронизация, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Скачал командную строку для работы с AWS (AWS CLI). Через `aws configure` прописал требуемые ключи для работы. 
Создал папку `new` внутри директории `/mnt` при помощи команды:

```
mkdir -m 777 new
```

Далее прописываю следующую команду:

```
sudo aws s3 sync s3://<MY_BUCKET> /mnt/new
```

На выходе получаю следующее:

```
download failed: s3://<MY_BUCKET>/. to ./. [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/mnt/new/..F853B54D' -> '/mnt/new/.'
```

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался весьма простым и связан с моей невнимательностью. На `S3` среди файлов оказался один с простым именем `.` (одна точка). Ubuntu такое название не нравится, поэтому оно и ругалось